# Plotly Express scatter_mapbox not rendering in Dash

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, plotly-dash

I have a Python application that I am attempting to put into a Dash dashboard, but I am having some trouble with Mapbox rendering. I have a scatter map that works fine when I call it locally:

[image]

but when I try to deploy it through Dash, it renders on a blank x-y axis:

[image]

Any ideas as to what I might be missing? It only appears to be happening with Plotly *express* objects, as I have other maps that are `plotly.graph_objects.Scattermapbox` objects that render fine.

Reproducible example below (note that the commented out `specFig.show()` is what works locally):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain
import plotly.express as px
import geopy.distance
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

baseCols = [
'dbn'
,'school_name'
,'borocode'
,'overview_paragraph'
,'borough'
,'latitude'
,'longitude'
,'bin'
,'bbl'
,'nta'
,'total_students'
,'neighborhood'
,'specialized'
]

MBToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2NvaGVuZGUiLCJhIjoiY2szemMxczZoMXJhajNrcGRsM3cxdGdibiJ9.2oazpPgLvgJGF9EBOYa9Wg'
px.set_mapbox_access_token(MBToken)

df = pd.read_csv('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/23z9-6uk9.csv')

specDF = df[baseCols]

specSchools = specDF[specDF['specialized'].notna() == True][['school_name'
                                                             ,'overview_paragraph'
                                                             ,'borough'
                                                             ,'latitude'
                                                             ,'longitude'
                                                             ,'total_students'
                                                            ,'neighborhood']]

specSchools['total_students'] = pd.to_numeric(specSchools['total_students'])

specFig = px.scatter_mapbox(specSchools.dropna()
                        , lat="latitude"
                        , lon="longitude"
                        , color="borough"
                        , size="total_students"
                        , text="school_name"
                        , hover_name="school_name"
                        , hover_data=["neighborhood"]
                        , size_max=15
                        , zoom=9
                       )

#specFig.show()

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([html.H1('NYC Specialized Schools')], style={'textAlign': 'center'}),
    dcc.Graph(children=specFig),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute of the Graph component that you want to be setting to your figure is not `children`, but `figure`:

```
dcc.Graph(figure=specFig)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. However, that changes it from a blank axis to completely blank image (except that now it shows the legend)

Comment: That's strange. I ran your app with the change I mentioned and it seemed to be working ok. So I'm not sure what the issue is now.